# sort an array based on an array of another/different type in haskell or purescript

Tags: arrays, sorting, haskell, functional-programming, purescript

I have two Arrays of different types, 1) say `moduleinfo` array which has each element of type

`{name :: String, pack :: String }`

and 2) `String` Array. The simple `String` array contains element that is similar to the `name` field of `moduleinfo`, i.e `String`. The simple `String` array is already sorted but not the `moduleinfo` array.

How do I write a function to sort the `moduleinfo` array based on the order of simple `String` array. Given that the `name` field in `moduleinfo` would match with simple `String` array elements.

The function shall return a sorted array of `moduleinfo` type.

Comment: What should happen if one of the `name`s isn’t present in the sorted list of `String`s?

Comment: I suggest that you sort `moduleinfo` directly.

Comment: Note that you should post complete code that will compile. In particular, `{name :: String, pack :: String }` causes compiler errors because you are missing `data` and a name for the data type.

Comment: Use the sorted array to make a hashmap or triemap from module name to index in the sorted array.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you sort `moduleinfo` directly:

```
sortedModuleInfo = sortWith (\(Module name1 pack1) (Module name2 pack2) -> compare name1 name2) moduleinfo
```

Here I assume that you have declared a type named  `Module` with the `name` and `pack` elements which you showed in your question.